# valgrind shows memory leak in hostname command output

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind, hostname

I was just playing around with valgrind and randomly decided to check valgrind output for some linux commands.

Tried `ls -lrth` and it worked fine. At least no bytes in `definitely lost`.

However `hostname` command's output shows something which I was not expecting, i.e. a memory leak.

Is the hostname command buggy or am I missing something.
Your comments are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
==19877== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19877== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19877== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19877== Command: hostname
==19877== 
--19877-- Valgrind options:
--19877--    --leak-check=full
--19877--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--19877--    --track-origins=yes
--19877--    --verbose
--19877-- Contents of /proc/version:
--19877--   Linux version 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 14:49:43 UTC 2018
--19877-- 
--19877-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-avx-avx2-bmi
--19877-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--19877-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib64/valgrind
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/bin/hostname
--19877--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--19877--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--19877--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--19877-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--19877-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib64/valgrind/default.supp
==19877== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-19877-by-compuser-on-lenovoe470.localdomain
==19877== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-19877-by-compuser-on-lenovoe470.localdomain
==19877== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-19877-by-compuser-on-lenovoe470.localdomain
==19877== 
==19877== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==19877== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==19877== or are doing some strange experiment):
==19877==   /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=19877 ...command...
==19877== 
==19877== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==19877==   /path/to/gdb hostname
==19877== and then give GDB the following command
==19877==   target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=19877
==19877== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==19877== 
--19877-- REDIR: 0x4019d70 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x58059dd1 (???)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x4019b40 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x58059deb (???)
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
==19877== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--19877--     old: 0x04019d70 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x58059dd1 ???
--19877--     new: 0x04019d70 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c2ca70 strlen
--19877-- REDIR: 0x4019cf0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2dbc0 (strcmp)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x401a9b0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c30c40 (mempcpy)
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
--19877-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50df700 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50dc480 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50e19d0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50deee0 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50dee90 (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50dde70 (libc.so.6:__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4c2c430 (__GI_strrchr)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50dde30 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x518fd90 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2c4c0 (__strrchr_sse42)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50da900 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a24740 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x518e000 (libc.so.6:__strcmp_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2db70 (__strcmp_sse42)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50dc3a0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4c2c9d0 (__GI_strlen)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50d5160 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c29b3c (malloc)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50e4110 (libc.so.6:__GI_memcpy) redirected to 0x4c2e560 (__GI_memcpy)
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50de570 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x4c2dc60 (memchr)
lenovoe470.localdomain
--19877-- REDIR: 0x50d5580 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ac36 (free)
==19877== 
==19877== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19877==     in use at exit: 128 bytes in 1 blocks
==19877==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 128 bytes allocated
==19877== 
==19877== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==19877== Checked 86,656 bytes
==19877== 
==19877== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==19877==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==19877==    by 0x401737: ??? (in /usr/bin/hostname)
==19877==    by 0x401ADE: ??? (in /usr/bin/hostname)
==19877==    by 0x401473: ??? (in /usr/bin/hostname)
==19877==    by 0x50723D4: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==19877== 
==19877== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19877==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 1 blocks
==19877==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19877==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19877==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19877==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19877== 
==19877== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==19877== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why would you be surprised? Aside from poor code quality many utils simply don't bother with memory deallocation because process immediately ends anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I was expecting it not to be leaky, hence I got surprised. What is meant by ".. don't bother because process immediately ends anyway." Does it mean that when process ends, it takes care of it?

Comment: @User9102d82 The memory allocated is virtual memory in the process address space. When the process terminates, its address space no longer exists, so any virtual memory allocated in the address space no longer exists either.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Thank you for your comment. I understand now.

Comment: What is the question here? How to report a bug? (If so, send it to [Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)). Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing debugging information, I get this:

```
==31026== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==31026==    at 0x483880B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==31026==    by 0x10A827: localhost (hostname.c:129)
==31026==    by 0x10ABE6: show_name (hostname.c:264)
==31026==    by 0x10A556: main (hostname.c:547)
```

Looking at the sources of the `hostname` command, the `localhost` function is called at most three times before the program exists.  So this memory leak is complete bounded.  The programmer probably thought that freeing this memory would not matter because the kernel will free all memory of the process when it is terminated anyway.  In such cases, manual deallocation only causes the program to run a little bit longer, without conserving any memory resources.

For larger programs, such a micro-optimization might still be problematic because it makes debugging *real* memory leaks so much harder if many allocations are affected.  But `hostname` is very small, so this is not a concern here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please advise upon whether this is an acceptable practice or trend in the industry or is it that since it's implicit,the program is short and kernel will free memory anyways - so why bother doing a useless spite.

Comment: As I said, `hostname` is very small and unlikely to have  real memory leaks of its own, so I don't think this is a problem in practice. For larger programs, I would likely see this fixed.

Comment: There are some people who feel very strongly that any memory leaked at the end of process execution is an intolerable, serious error that must be fixed. There are also some people who think it doesn't matter at all so long as it can't accumulate during process execution and cause real problems. It's a contentious question with most people somewhere in the middle.